# Display selected row data in another component using Material UI/React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am running into a bit of a problem grabbing data from a Data Grid (or XGrid) to display in another component on the page.

From the code below you can see that I am grabbing data from a local database that I am displaying in a Data Grid. What I want to do now is add the ability to take the selected rows and display the data (product ID, description, price, etc.) and display it in another component. Right now, I will settle for just a single selection.

I have tried many suggestions found here to add a `onSelectionModelChange`, but the only thing I am able to grab is the row `id` value. Not that it would make that much difference, but I am using MySQL for the backend.

Any suggestions?

Here's my React file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { GridToolbarDensitySelector, GridToolbarFilterButton, XGrid } from '@material-ui/x-grid';

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
});

const usdPrice = {
    type: 'number',
    width: 180,
    valueFormatter: ({ value }) => currencyFormatter.format(Number(value)),
    cellClassName: 'font-tabular-nums',
};

const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const useStyles = makeStyles(
    (theme) => ({
        root: {
            padding: theme.spacing(0.5, 0.5, 0),
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            background: '#f3f5f6'
        },
        textField: {
            [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
                width: '100%',
            },
            margin: theme.spacing(1, 0.5, 1.5),
            '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                marginRight: theme.spacing(0.5),
            },
            '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
                borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
            },
        },
    }),
    { defaultTheme },
);

function FilteringToolbar() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div>
                <GridToolbarFilterButton />
                <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const ProductTable = () => {

    const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState([]);
    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(rowData);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const axios = require('axios').default;
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response) => {
            setRows(response.data);
        }).catch(e => {
            window.alert(e);
        });
    }, [rowData]);

    const columns = [
        { field: 'prodID', headerName: 'Product ID', width: 130, disableReorder: true } ,
        { field: 'desc', headerName: 'Description', width: 200, editable: true, disableReorder: true },
        { field: 'price', headerName: 'Price', editable: true, disableReorder: true, ...usdPrice },
        { field: 'inStock', headerName: 'In Stock', width: 110, editable: true, disableReorder: true, headerAlign: 'center', align: 'center', type: 'boolean'},
        { field: 'new', headerName: 'New', width: 110, editable: true, disableReorder: true, headerAlign: 'center', align: 'center', type: 'boolean' },
    ]

    return (
        <Grid container item xs={12}>
            <Grid container item xs={12}>
                <Grid container item xs={3} />
                <Grid container item xs={6} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <div style={{ height: 500, width: '100%', display: 'block', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto' }}>
                    <XGrid checkboxSelection {...rows}
                        components={{ Toolbar: FilteringToolbar }}
                        rows={rows}
                        columns={columns}
                        id="id"
                    />
            </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default ProductTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of trying to get the row data that you need to pass to any child/related components *from* the table, you get the data *directly* from your own component's state. Since you already have the `id`s returned from `onSelectionModelChange`, you can simply use them to filter the `rows` state to get the selected items.  For example:

```
...

const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);

const handleSelectionChange = React.useCallback(
  (selected = []) => {
    setSelected(rows.filter(({ prodID }) => selected.includes(prodID)));
  },
  [rows] 
);

...
```

```
<XGrid
  // Calls our handler function that filters the selected items from state
  onSelectionModelChange={handleSelectionChange}
  checkboxSelection
  {...rows}
  components={{ Toolbar: FilteringToolbar }}
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  // Re-wires the grid to use your `prodID` instead of it's default `id`
  getRowId={({ prodID }) => prodID}
/>
```

[image: Demo Example]

Working Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-selected-items-rm3f1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I will wait for other answers but if none are provided, I will award you the bounty for this question.

Comment: Thanks @hfontanez -- let me know if you need any additional clarity on the what I'm doing here.